# How to access a Samba shared folder from a Pi

Tags: samba, file-sharing

In my home network I have an Ubuntu machine that is running Samba server. My Windows machine is easily able to browse through the folders after providing a username and password.
However when I try to run `smb://server` from my Raspberry Pi 2 it is not able to access the shared folder(s). What am I doing wrong as I am a newbie in the Pi World.

Comment: What's the output from smb://server?

Comment: it didnt go thru,letme look for the output and attach forgive me that was a while back letme find the Rasp Pi, I resorted to turning my old desktop to an Ubuntu server and installing everything there

Answer (score 2):

You can use mount command

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.x.x/<your-share> /home/pi/my-share username=pi, password=mypass
```

You may need to install `cifs-utils`

Comment: tried this already it did not work.but when I use smbclient I can view the contents of the folder.

Answer (score -1):

```
apt-get install samba-common smbclient samba-common-bin smbclient
```

Then try it

Comment: You have `smbclient` twice, and besides the OP said he had it installed.

Comment: this did not make a difference when I tried it then but I will re run